# Cache for Angular2

Tags: caching, typescript, angular

I am looking for a cache implementation for an Angular2 application.

For example, we have a million `Movie` objects stored on a server (i.e. enough that we don't want to grab them all at once). On the server, a REST endpoint is available : `getMovie(String id)`

Back on the client side, the cache should provide a simple way to get a movie from Angular, something like `cache.getMovie(id:string): Observable<Movie>`. This will hit the REST endpoint only for the first call, and store it locally for later requests.

Angular1 has [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) or the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), with LRU support and other great functionalities.

I started implementing a basic cache using a local HashMap, but that seems like a very common need.

Is there a good in-memory cache implementation for Angular2 yet?

Comment: I don't know of how frameworks tend to go about this, but I imagine a very basic implementation could be done in less than 50 lines, and preserve Movie references as values in an object. eg: `{ mv_5234: (Movie) }`. If Movies can be stored as text, you can also put them in localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [lscache](https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache) and extend it providing few underlying storages: localStorage, sessionStorage, and self-implmented memoryStorage. TypeScript definitions are already available.